# What is the grammatical function of "evident" in "Within us, ...., there is evident a serious and purposeful rekindling of confidence"?

Tags: word-usage

What is the grammatical function of "evident" in

> Within us, the people of the United States, there is evident a serious and purposeful rekindling of confidence

It is from [*Inaugural Address of Jimmy Carter*](https://avalon.law.yale.edu/20th_century/carter.asp).

Answer (score 2):

Evident is an adjective:

- *Clearly seen or understood; obvious.*
   [[Lexico]](http://Clearly%20seen%20or%20understood;%20obvious.)

It modifies 'rekindling of confidence.'

Comment: If it is an adjective, how come it is followed by an "a"?

Comment: If t modifies 'rekindling of confidence', why is it not put in this way:  an evident, serious, and purposeful rekindling of confidence?

Comment: It is an odd word-order. It _sounds_ good (to me), but your word-order is certainly the standard one. I'm trying to think of a similar example.

Comment: I guess it's like "...there is visible a large black rain-cloud"

Comment: A serious and purposeful rekindling of confidence is evident within us, the people of the United States.

Comment: Thanks, @Lucian, Then what is the grammatical function of "evident" in the original sentence?

Comment: @EricMiller, this answer is ok. Definitely you can accept it. Just the word order is different.